# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string .net ADO

Tags: .net, database, ado.net

I am inserting data from **dateTimePicker** in WFA to data base using ADO. Data base have **Date** dataType - **YYYY/MM/DD**. So i'm short date from **dateTimePicker** to ShortDateFormat. So wouldn't it be **YYYY/MM/DD**? I got this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                        {
                            string query = "Insert Into Users VALUES (@Name, @Lastname, @Phone, @birthDate, @Image)";
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                            {
                                string FileName = btnImgPath.Text;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tbName.Text;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tbLastname.Text;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tbPhone.Text;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.Date, 100).Value = dtp1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imageData;

                                conn.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                conn.Close();
                            }
                         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code passes a string to a date-typed parameter :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.Date, 100).Value = dtp1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

This needs to be parsed back to a `DateTime` before it's sent to the database.

Pass the `DateTime` value directly instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtp1.Value.Date;
```

The [DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) property returns a DateTime without the original value's time part.

There's no need to specify a size either, as `date` is a fixed-size type